How to handle Data Normalization in case that a Logarithmic scale is required?
Let's say we wished to build a Regressor (e.g. a Support Vector Regressor) to predict the price of an asset, within a given time span from now on.
However, what if the historical data we have collected does not follow a consistent scale, due to the performance of the asset itself.
Some observations are in the order of units or between 0 and 1; and some others may be hundreds or thousands times greater.
Typical normalization procedures would not be a good suit in this case.
If we tried StandardScaler, for example, both the mean and the variance would not be representative of the underlying data trends. Thus, many of the points would have been regarded as outliers —while they are not.
What measures could you take, to get rid of this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Why do you want to normalize at all, and why do you believe the mean and variance not to be representative of the underlying data trends?

@Dave From the user guide (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#tips-on-practical-use): “Support Vector Machine algorithms are not scale invariant, so it is highly recommended to scale your data.”

So then why not scale your data as is recommended?

@Dave Because some regions would get over/under represented, due to the scale differences among them. Think of gold price, for example. In the 1960s it has been trading at USD 40 levels.
Today is worth over USD 2000, which historically had never happened, but today's reality needs to be taken in account in order to get a good prediction.

I do not follow the issue. All the scaling does is a unit conversion, nothing different than working in meters instead of kilometers or in miles instead of feet. Could you please elaborate on what you find problematic about scaling the data?
